# textmate - moving project drawer to right side

Tags: textmate

is this seriously the solution to this problem?

http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/how-to-move-textmate-project-drawer-left-right-side

Comment: this is probably a better question for superuser

Comment: this should be a preference setting : show project drawer on? right or left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better solution.

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakProjectDrawerPrefersRightEdge -bool NO
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the drawer will still open on whatever side it has more room on.

Comment: `defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fileBrowserPlacement right` should work for OSX. Changing the last part of the command from `right` to `left` will switch it back to the left side.

Answer (score 24):

You can do it this way:

in the menu -> View -> Hide project drawer

then move the textmate window to the side of the screen e.g. far left if you want the drawer on the right side

then back to the menu -> View -> show project drawer

it will open on whichever side it has room based on where you placed the window on the screen.

Comment: This solution is not working for TextMate 2. Please look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795726/how-to-move-the-textmate-file-explorer-to-the-right-side in case if you are using latest versions.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, yes. As far as I know, that is the only way to force TextMate to change the side the drawer is on.

Answer (score 2):

If you have it installed, go to Preferences > Project+ > Sidebar and select "Show sidebar on the right side of the window".