# how to move the textmate file explorer to the right side?

Tags: textmate

how to move the textmate file explorer to the right side?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can move textmate to the left edge of the screen and close and open the panel. ie. ctrl, alt, cmd + d.

Answer (score 32):

Update:

For later versions of textmate, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817213/908886)

---

For Textmate 2 (released long after this question was answered) the accepted answer doesn't appear to work anymore. This is what did it for me:

To change it to the right on OSX, open up your terminal and run the command:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fileBrowserPlacement right
```

To change it to the left:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fileBrowserPlacement left
```

Comment: Theres also an option in preferences - projects to set the side if your project is already loaded :).

Answer (score 14):

TextMate --> Preferences --> Projects --> Show file browser on: --> Left side / Right side

[image]

Comment: on the latest version for Mac (2.0.23) this now shows up under "Settings" instead of "Preferences"

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/category/textmate) by Ciarán Walsh, I highly recommend it. It makes some small but helpful improvements to TextMate's project features. It also allows you to specify the default side for the project drawer (which actually becomes a nice panel).

If you have it installed, go to Preferences > Project+ > Sidebar and select "Show sidebar on the right side of the window".